# How to prevent Firefox tab title from being used as window title in Windows?

Tags: windows-10, firefox, firefox-extensions

I want the Firefox Window title to stay the same irrespective of the selected tab  title. For example window name can be "Mozilla Firefox". It can be anything else too but it should not include the tab title.

OS: Windows 10

Firefox Version: 93.0

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no built-in feature in Firefox to do achieve what you want.

An option would be to change all tabs titles, some extensions are able to do this:
https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/search/?q=tab title
I've tried with "Rename Tab Title" with `/*/` as regexp, and it makes the job.
But then, it might be difficult to browse through your tabs, since they will all have the same name

Another option could be to hide the title bar (right-click on the Firefox toolbar > "Customize toolbar" > uncheck the "Title bar" at bottom left)